# Binding using std::bind vs lambdas. How expensive are they?

Tags: c++11, lambda, stdbind

I was playing with bind and I was thinking, are lambdas as expensive as function pointers?

What I mean is, as I understand lambdas, they are syntactic sugar for functors and bind is similar.  However, if you do this:

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>

void fn2(int a, int b)
{
  std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
}

void fn1(int a, int b)
{
  //auto bound = std::bind(fn2, a, b);
  //static auto bound = std::bind(fn2, a, b);
  //auto bound = [&]{ fn2(a, b); };
  static auto bound = [&]{ fn2(a, b); };
  bound();
}

int main()
{
  fn1(3, 4);
  fn1(1, 2);
  return 0;
}
```

Now, if I were to use the 1st `auto bound = std::bind(fn2, a, b);`, I get an output of

> 3, 4

1, 2, the 2nd I get

> 3, 4

3, 4. The 3rd and 4th I get output like the 1st.

Now I get why the 1st and 2nd work that way, they are getting initialised at the beginning of the function call (the static one, only the 1st time it is called).  However, 3 and 4 seem to have compiler magic going on where the generated functors are not really creating references to the enclosing scope's variables, but are actually latching on to the symbols whether or not it is initialised only the first time or every time.

Can someone clarify what is actually happening here?

**Edit**: What I was missing is using `static auto bound = std::bind(fn2, std::ref(a), std::ref(b));` to have it work as the 4th option.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The different result is that `a` and `b` will not be available to the lambda function.  That's obvious.  What are you trying to show me?

Comment: Damn, I meant: Try with capturing by value instead of by reference, e.g. `[=]{ ... }`. That is what's done when you use `std::bind`, it "captures" the variables by value.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ah, right.  The 2nd works like the 4th if I use `std::ref` around `a` and `b`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have this code:

```
static auto bound = [&]{ fn2(a, b); };
```

Assignment is done only first time you are invoking this function because it's `static`. So in fact it's called only once. Compiler creates closure when you are making lambdas, so references to a and b from first call to fn1 was captured. It's very risky. It may lead to dangling references. I'm surprised it didn't crashed since you are making closure from function parameters passed by value - to local variables.

I recommend this excellent article about lambdas: http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html .

Comment: It absolutely leads to dangling references. They're bound to objects `a` and `b`, which cease to exists as soon as the function returns for the first time.

Comment: This is what I had thought and it didn't make sense.  I was thinking that some sort of compiler magic was going on.  No, instead it was just random magic. :)  It probably worked only because I called from the same function one after the other.  I was hoping to make a type of "vector table" using this method, but this will be too expensive as it will have to generate the table of functors(using bind or lambda) every time the function is entered.  In which case, I'll just go with reg function or member function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, only use `[&]` lambdas when your closure is going to go away by the end of the current scope.

If it is going to outlast the current scope, and you *need* by-reference, explicitly capture the things you are going to capture, or create local pointers to the things you are going to capture and capture them by-value.

In your case, your `static` lambda code is full of undefined behavior, as you `[&]` capture `a` and `b` in the first call, then use it in the second call.

In theory, the compiler could rewrite your code to capture `a` and `b` by value instead of by reference, then call that every time, because the only difference between that implementation and the one you wrote occurs when the behavior is undefined, and the result will be much faster.

It could do a more efficient job by ignoring your `static` completely, as the entire state of your `static` object is undefined after you leave scope the first time you call, and the construction has no visible side effects.

To fix your problem with the lambdas, use `[=]` or `[a,b]` to introduce the lambda, and it will capture the `a` and `b` by value.  I prefer to capture state explicitly on lambdas when I expect the lambda to persist longer than the current block.